# Dynamic CQL filter in leaflet.js

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, heat-map

Tell me, please, how I can apply cql_filter, based on currently map location in leaflet.js.

I have following code:

```
var myLayer = L.tileLayer.wms("url-to-geoserver", 
{
    layers: 'heatmap:layer',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,

});
```

and I need to apply (on each map ondragstop event I guess) cql filter  like this: (geom+IS+NOT+NULL+AND+l_room+IS+NOT+NULL+AND+BBOX(geom,55.46187404873886,37.52260208129883,55.46845504793832,37.56232023239136)).

Help me with this, please, or give some keywords for further googling.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a [parameter called `cql_filter` to geoserver](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#cql-filter) so just add it to the layer options.

```
var myLayer = L.tileLayer.wms("url-to-geoserver", 
{
    layers: 'heatmap:layer',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    cql_filter: '(geom+IS+NOT+NULL+AND+l_room+IS+NOT+NULL+AND+BBOX(geom,55.46187404873886,37.52260208129883,55.46845504793832,37.56232023239136))'
});
```

However WMS will automatically filter by the bounding box and ignore geometries that are null so you should be able to simplify that to `l_room+IS+NOT+NULL`.